# Using Jmeter bean shell scripting how can i extract an integer from a string

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

In Jmeter I have extracted a JSON string 
String is : {"status":"ok","errorCode":0,"message":null,"data":{"userCount":2}}
and I have extracted data:{"userCount":2} using JSON path extractor.

Now I need to extract '2' from {"userCount":2} . How can i acheive this using bean shell scripting.

Answer (score 1):

use $data.userCount as JSON path expression in JSON path extractor

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend considering switching to [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) language, this way you will be able to kill two birds with one stone as [Groovy has built-in JSON support](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html) and performs much better than Beanshell. The relevant code to extract this `2` as an integer from the parent sampler response will be as simple as:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString())
int userCount = json.data.userCount as int
//do what you need with this "userCount integer"
```

See [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details.